# controller code : display success after form submission and redirect url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Can anyone share Controller and View code for after form submission, display success message and clean up input text boxes in `MVC5` `C#` ? I have `ajax` call from the View page to Controller like this.

```
 $("input#btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
                $.ajax({       type: "POST",
                                    url: "/Home/Submit",
                                    contentType: "application/json",
                                    data :("form#myWAREntryForm").serialize(),
                                    dataType: "JSON",
                                    success: function (data) {                                    
                                       window.location.reload();                                        
                                    }
                                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown) {alert("error" + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
                }
                 }); // Ajax End                              
            }); // Submit button click
```

Action method is as below.

```
public ActionResult Submit() 
{ 
   NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form; 
   LineItem weeklyActivityReportLineItem = new LineItem { CustomerNumber = 
   String.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["customerNumber"])?0:Convert.ToInt32(nvc["customerNumber"]),VisitTypeId = String.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["visitType"]) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(nvc["visitType"]),ReportId = 5}; 
SaveChanges(); 
return Json(new {success =true },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Comment: Please update with code examples of what you have tried so far and elaborate on what/where in your code you need some certain behaviour.

Comment: public ActionResult  Submit()
{   NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
    LineItem weeklyActivityReportLineItem = new LineItem 
    {  CustomerNumber = String.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["customerNumber"])?0:Convert.ToInt32(nvc["customerNumber"]),VisitTypeId = 
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["visitType"]) ? 0 : 
    Convert.ToInt32(nvc["visitType"]),ReportId = 5};   
    SaveChanges();
    return Json(new {success =true },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

Comment: I just added View code (ajax) and controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution

```
 $("input#btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
                    $.ajax({       type: "POST",
                                        url: "/Home/Submit",
                                        contentType: "application/json",
                                        data :("form#myWAREntryForm").serialize(),
                                        dataType: "JSON",
                                        success: function (data) {                                    
                                         if(data.success){ //Show success message //clear your controls here }else{//other message}                                       
                                        }
                                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown) {alert("error" + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
                    }
                     }); // Ajax End                              
                }); // Submit button click
```

Action method would be.

```
public JsonResult Submit() 
{ 
   NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form; 
   LineItem weeklyActivityReportLineItem = new LineItem { CustomerNumber = 
   String.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["customerNumber"])?0:Convert.ToInt32(nvc["customerNumber"]),VisitTypeId = String.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["visitType"]) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(nvc["visitType"]),ReportId = 5}; 
SaveChanges(); 
return Json(new {success =true },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Comment: It's still not knowing success event in ajax return.